# Вставить сразу после тега body тег div

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В тексте html страницы необходимо сразу же после тега  вставить свой тег  с учетом возможных атрибутов тега

К примеру, было:

```
 <body class="myclass">....</body>
```

стало:

```
 <body class="myclass"><div>....</div></body>
```

Было:

```
 <body>....</body>
```

стало:

```
 <body><div>....</div></body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При условии, что тег `body` в единственном экземпляре

```
$html = '<body class="myclass">....</body>';
$html = preg_replace(array(
                       '%(<body.*?>)%i',
                       '%(</body>)%i'
                     ), array(
                       '$1<div>',
                       '</div>$1'
                     ), $html);
```

Comment: @ReinRaus, как что? Содержимое 1й группы из регулярного выражения.